# Error handling when expecting argument

Tags: python, if-statement

First post, also first attempt to code something beyond 99 bottles...

I am working on code which accepts an argument from the cli such as a text file. Expected usage would be:

*$:myfile.py input.txt*

I've got that piece going smoothly however if an argument is not supplied, the cli returns an error and i'd like to provide some error response such as a help list or just a simple "Nope - give me a file"

Right now here is the first few lines:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    ifile = f.read()
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        empty = "Please give me something to do!"
        print empty
```

If i supply the expected argument, everything is fine, but if no argument is supplied, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Lets say I just want the variable "Empty" to print if the condition isn't met... what would i do to fix that.

edit: after trying one of the suggestion below with argparse I am getting better results but I notice argparse throwing in a character I am not expecting. The code is now:

```
   def main(filename):
    # do something with filename
    print('your filename is %s' % filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program help')
    parser.add_argument('-f', help='specify file path')
```

when I run this I expect to see -h and -f as options but I see an extra F in the description.

```
my program help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -f F        specify macro file path
```

Can you tell me how to get rid of this extra F. I have tried a few things but it either appears, or I get errors when I run it.

Comment: of course it fail, you need to check the length of sys.argv before you you try to open something, not after

Answer (score 3):

use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for parsing cli input arguments:

example code for your case:

```
import argparse


def main(filename):
    # do something with filename
    print('your filename is %s' % filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program help')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='your desired filename')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.filename)
```

running from terminal without argument we get:

```
$ python ans_argparse.py
usage: ans_argparse.py [-h] filename
ans_argparse.py: error: the following arguments are required: filename
```

running with arguments:

```
$ python ans_argparse.py 'myfile.txt'
your filename is 'myfile.txt'
```

**creating custom parser may take time and is not that straight forward. 
`argparse` has lots of features and is embedded inside the stdlib so prefer to use it.**

### Another Example

I usually create `parse_args()` function so testing it or invoking it outside of `__main__` is easier:

```
import sys
import argparse


def main(filename):
    # do something with filename
    print('your filename is %s' % filename)


def parse_args(args_lst):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my program help')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='your desired filename')
    return parser.parse_args(args_lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])                 
    main(args.filename)
```

and you can call it like this:

```
args = parse_args(['another_filename.txt'])
```

### Update

use the `metavar` optional argument for changing the display name of the variable on the help. I encourage you to read the doc of [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more examples and use cases

like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='FILENAME', required=True, 
                    help='the file path for this program')
```

output of `python myprog.py --help`:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -f FILENAME  the file path for this program
```

**note:** do not forget the `required=True` argument so you'll get an error message from `argparse`.

Comment: thanks, I edited my post with the results. It's working great but I have a rogue character and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: I edited my post with `metavar` example for your use case, please update if works with the new changes

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is great, but you can also keep it simple

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: myfile.py textfile\n")
    exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    pass # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the correctitude of sys.argv before you do something with it, if you do after that is to late obviously.

Like this for example

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    #do something
else:
    print "Please give me something to do!"
```